# Does it still make sense using json endpoint ep_mask now that there's the new rest api?

Tags: rewrite-rules, api, rest-api, endpoints

I was wondering... Maybe I don't get the point here, don't know. I think that the rewrite api is still usefull for creating beautiful frontend urls for regular users. But I'm not sure on adding a json endpoint via ep_masks (for example: https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/).

Isn'it a thing already covered by the new rest api? Am I missing something?

And by the way... Time to create a 'rest-api' tag here in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Close voting as opinion based, as the answer will most likely depend on the exact thing you want to do and you preference in building end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should stop using rewrite endpoints to handle JSON responses. Instead you can and you should use the REST API.

So, instead of this:

```
function makeplugins_add_json_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'json', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'makeplugins_add_json_endpoint' );
```

And then handle the JSON response at your own, you can and you should do something like this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'cyb_register_api_endpoints' );
function cyb_register_api_endpoints() {

    $namespace = 'myplugin/v1';

    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/myendpoint/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'cyb_myendpoint_callback',
    ) );

}

function cyb_myendpoint_callback() {

    //$response can be a Object, JSON, array
    $response = [];

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response );

}
```

In conclusion: a JSON endpoint should be handle now through REST API.